# Move data in Waterfall-Dialog. Bot Framework SDK

Tags: node.js, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm using Bot Framework SDK with nodejs to implement a disamibuation flow.

I want that if two intents predicted by Luis are close to each other, ask the user from which of them are the one they want. I have done the validator but, I have a problem with the flow.

It is a waterfall Dialog with 3 steps:

1. FirstStep: Calls Orchestrator and Luis to get intents and entities. It pass the data with `return await step.next({...})`
2. Disamiguation Step: Checks if it is necessary to disambiguate, and, in that case, prompts the options. If not, it pass the data like the first step.
3. Answer step: If it has a disambiguation flag in the data it receives in `step.result`, it prompts the answer acordingly with the user response. Elsewhere, it uses the data in `step.result` that comes from the first step.

The problem is that, when it prompts user to say the intent, I lost the data of the FirstStep since I cannot use `step.next({...})`

¿How can I maintain both the data from the first step and the user answer in the prompt?

Here are the basic code:

```
 async firstStep(step) {
        logger.info(`FinalAnswer Dialog: firstStep`);
        let model_dispatch = await this.bot.get_intent_dispatch(step.context);
        let result = await this.bot.dispatchToTopIntentAsync(step.context, model_dispatch.model)
        // model_dispatch = orchestrator_model
        // result = {topIntent: String, entities: Array, disamibiguation: Array}

        return await step.next({ model_dispatch: model_dispatch, result: result})
    }

    async disambiguationStep(step) {
        logger.info(`FinalAnswer Dialog: disambiguationStep`);
        if (step.result.result.disambiguation) {
            logger.info("We need to disambiguate")
            let disambiguation_options = step.result.result.disambiguation
            const message_text = "What do you need";
            const data = [
                {
                    "title": "TEXT",
                    "value": disambiguation_option[0]
                },
                {
                    "title": "TEXT",
                    "value": disambiguation_option[1]
                },
            ]

            let buttons = data.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
                    title: d.title,
                    value: d.value
                }
            });

            const msg = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(buttons, message_text);
            return await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, { prompt: msg });
            return step.next(step.result) //not working
        }
        else {
            logger.info("We dont desambiguate")
            return step.next(step.result)
        }
    }

    async answerStep(step) {
        logger.info(`FinalAnswer Dialog: answerStep`);
        let model_dispatch = step.result.model_dispatch
        let result = step.result.result

        //Show answer
 
        return await step.endDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the step dictionary to store your values. The complex dialogs sample on GitHub is excellent for demonstrating this. https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/43.complex-dialog/dialogs/topLevelDialog.js

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in the context with whatever name you want:

```
step.values['nameProperty'] = {}
```

This will be accessible within the entire execution context of the waterfall dialog:

```
const data = step.values['nameProperty'] // {}
```